# Memory map directly to string

Tags: java, memory-mapped-files

I have a file I'm mapping into memory via 'FileChannel.map()'. However it seems a bit odd when reading a string to do the following:

```
1) read a int for the string length
2) allocate a byte[length] object
3) use .get to read length bytes
4) convert the byte[] to a string
```

Now I know from my C++ background that memory mapped files are given to the user as pointers to memory. So is there a good way to skip using a byte array and just have the string conversion go right off the mapped memory?

Comment: That's to be determined at this point. Currently it's ASCII.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest:

```
MappedByteBuffer mapped = fileChannel.map(mode, position, size);
String s = new String(mapped.array());
```

It is also possible to use the mapped.asCharBuffer() and get the chars by this way.

Comment: To prevent the unnecessary copy to a buffer, this is the way to do it. Of course, making a string still involves a copy, as rlibby mentioned.

Comment: ...so that he can get an `UnsupportedOperationException`?  `MappedByteBuffer` is not backed by an array, `MappedByteBuffer.hasArray()` returns `false`, and `MappedByteBuffer.array()` throws the above exception.

Comment: It could be true, so, he will need to use asCharBuffer() and read each char to another buffer and so on construct the string.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, no. But there is a way to get a view of the data as characters. Look at ByteBuffer.asCharBuffer().

Internally, the asCharBuffer() method does the same thing you're proposing, but on a char-by-char basis.

Comment: +1 that is the best he could possibly hope for, if the file is ASCII, because Java strings are Unicode..

Answer (score 1):

There's no getting around String wanting a private copy of the data.  Strings are immutable and if it used a shared array, you could break that.  It's unfortunate that there's no `String(CharSequence)` or `String(ByteBuffer)` constructor.